# Can questions be sandboxed in law.meta like they are in other Stacks?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have a question I'd like to ask on law.se, but I am not sure of the proper wording.

A few other Stacks (like codegolf, I believe) allow sandboxing questions on Meta, to later post them in the main Stack.

Is this practice allowed on Law? I used the search but no hints came for "sandbox".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not our usual practice. We are a relatively small community and the Meta community is even smaller and it's possible that your proposed question would languish back here without love (or hate)?

Just ask it on the main site, we'll love or hate it there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no policy that I know of **against** such sandboxing, but I have not seen it done in the several years I have been active here.  If you post,on the main site people may well make suggestions for improvement of a question, or even edit it directly for formatting.